# How to customize sub-URLs in a wordpress website (.htaccess)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url

I have a regular business website that I built on Wordpress - www.example.com

I have a blog page in my website under - www.example.com/blog

When viewing a blog post it looks like this: www.exmaple.com/[category]/[posts-name]

How can I add "/blog" to this URL before the category? 
like this: www.exmaple.com/blog/[category]/[posts-name]

This is my current .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!

WordPress settings->permalink.

Selected custom structure and entered:

> blog/%category%/%postname%